# XML mapping in Excel using tables

Tags: xml, excel, vbscript

I am using XML mapping in Excel to map data for elements to a table. When I map the element to the table header I get an XML error and this error `runtime error '-2147217406 (80041002)'` and it asks me to use `XmlMap.IsExportable`. When I map the XML element to a single cell it exports without issue.

I have tried changing my table to be only one row and it still gives me that error. I need to map it to the column header for the table so that everything I type into the table gets exported into XML.

I can provide my VBScript that I am using if anyone needs it but largely I am trying to figure out why mapping to a cell works but not to a table column header. This is something I did before in 2010 without issues and currently I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed most of it. Since i was using an XML doc with only 1 item in it, excel was having issues parsing it
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.misc/oS-5VPb4HRg